# How to set an empty Object's properties programatically?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, object, flex3, flex4

I'm doing some **Actionscript** work right now and I'd like to know whether there's a way to **initiate** an empty object's value programatically like this:

`var myObj:Object = new Object;`

`myObj.add("aKey","aValue");`

To add a property called `aKey` whose value is `aValue`

I need to create a "Dumb" (data-only) object to use as a parameter to send via POST. So I don't know offhand how long and/or how many attributes it's gonna have.

Or something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionScript 3 allows you to create new Objects using an expressive Object Literal syntax similar to the one found in JavaScript:

```
const myObj : Object = {
    aKey: "aValue",
};
trace(myObj.aKey); // "aValue"
```

If you want to assign properties after the object has been constructed then you can use either dot notation or square bracket notation, eg:

```
const myObj : Object = {};  // create an empty object.
myObj.aKey = "aValue";
myObj["anotherKey"] = "anotherValue";
```

If you plan on sending the data over HTTP, you may wish to consider looking at the [URLVariables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) class which will take care of URL encoding the data for you.

Comment: Oh wait a second. In the second method. Does `myObj.aKey="aValue"` work even if the `aKey` attribute doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes it works so! Object class is a dynamic so object can be altered at run time by adding or changing properties and methods.